# Angular currency pipe no decimal value

Tags: angular, angular5

I am trying to use the currency pipe in angular to display a whole number price, I don't need it to add .00 to my number, the thing is, its not formatting it according to my instructions.
here is my HTML:

```
              <h5 class="price"><span>{{billingInfo.amount | currency:billingInfo.currencyCode:'1.0-0'}}</span> {{billingInfo.period}}</h5>
```

here is my ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
      this.billingInfo = {amount: 100, currencyCode: 'USD', period: 'Hour'};
}
```

and here is the output:

```
$100.00 Hour
```

things I tried to do:

1.use the decimal number pipe(no good, the currency pipe turns it into a string)

2.add number formater(:1.0-0) to my currencyPipe but it seems to be ignored

what am I missing?

Comment: If you don't need decimals, then why are you using the decimal pipe ? Simply remove it ...

Answer (score 92):

To remove `.00` from the currency pipe you can use this pattern. See the digitsInfo section on [CurrencyPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe)  for more information.

```
{{ amount | currency : 'USD' : 'symbol' : '1.0-0' }}
```

If you don't need the decimal you can use the number pipe.

```
${{amount | number}}
```

Comment: I have 123.56. The above solution is not removing .56 from the value. How can I remove value which are non-zero ?

Comment: The currency pipe is for formatting your numbers so you could use:            
{{2.56 | currency : 'USD' : 'symbol' : '1.0-0'}} but this will round your number up.

Comment: You may want to create a custom pipe if your goal is to simply drop the decimal and not account for it. Something like this would check for decimal and remove if it exists. You can drop this vanilla js in a angular pipe and and you should have the result your going for.       
   let hasDecimal = (value).indexOf('.');
  (value && hasDecimal) ? (value).slice(0, hasDecimal ) : value

Comment: Also, note the question was how to remove ".00" not any decimal. My answer is only valid if the goal is to remove ".00". Your question is an entirely different use case. Dropping the decimal changes the number and if you want angular to do it through there pipe they are going to account for the decimal by rounding up or down not mutating the number which seems to be your goal, in which case a custom pipe would prob be a better solution.

Comment: Thanks mate. I'll try creating a new custom pipe.

Comment: If you use `{{ amount | currency : 'USD' : 'symbol' : '2.0-2' }}` it won't show any decimals when it's `.00` but it will show up to two decimals when you have them

Answer (score 6):

Best I can tell you're just missing the display parameter which is supposed to be the 2nd parameter to the currency pipe, so if you change it to the following it should work:

```
<h5 class="price"><span>{{billingInfo.amount | currency:billingInfo.currencyCode:'symbol':'1.0-0'}}</span> {{billingInfo.period}}</h5>
```

Answer (score 5):

**Here is my solution:**

```
amount = 5; //or 5.00;
{{ amount | currency: 'USD':true:'2.0' }}

Output would be: 5,
```

if the amount is set to `5.99` then the output would be `5.99`.

You can lean more from angular CurrencyPipe here https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe

Comment: Be aware that this will show "00" for a price of 0.0

Answer (score 5):

I was reading through this topic and didn't saw the "perfect" answer if you ask me. The following workaround i used to show the decimals if provided, but strip them if they are unwanted.

```
{{ value | currency: 'EUR':'symbol': (value % 1 == 0) ? '1.0-0': '1.2-2' }}
```

So as you can see the `value % 1 == 0` is a mod functionality that checks if the value is dividable by a whole number. If thats not the case it will return  `false`

```
(15.00 % 1 == 0) -> true
(15.50 % 1 == 0) -> false
```

Answer (score 3):

In Angular, to format a currency, use the currency pipe on a number as shown here.

```
<p>{{amount | currency:'USD':true:'1.2-2'}}</p>
```

- The first parameter, 'USD', of the pipe is an ISO currency code (e.g.
  ‘USD’,’EUR’, etc.)
- The second parameter, true, is an optional boolean to specify whether
  or not you want to render the currency symbol (‘$’, ‘€’); default is
  false
- The third parameter,'1.2-2', also optional, specifies how to format
  the number, using the same formatting rules as apply to the number
  pipe.

Answer (score 0):

reference https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe

```
    <h5 class="price"><span>{{billingInfo.amount | 
    currency:billingInfo.currencyCode:true:'1.0-0'}}</span> {{billingInfo.period}}</h5>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those looking to perform this currency formatting without decimals inside your TypeScript, you can use the CurrencyPipe's transform method like so:

```
import { CurrencyPipe } from '@angular/common';
```

```
constructor(private readonly currencyPipe: CurrencyPipe)

ngOnInit() {
      const billingAmount = 100;

      this.billingInfo = this.currencyPipe.transform(billingAmount, 'USD', 'symbol', '1.0-0');
}
```